# Dynamically create multiple link buttons with different values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop

I tried something like this.

```
xmlN = xml.SelectNodes("Table/Name")
For ctr = 0 To xmlN.Count - 1
Dim link as new LinkButton
link.ID= xmlN(ctr).InnerText
link.name=xmlN(ctr).InnerText
Panel1.controls.add(link)
Next
```

But I know it only makes one link where in all the values of xmlN is inside the link is there any way that I can create new link button every loop?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set
    link.Text = "any value" , 
otherwise the client will not be able to see the link.